# move an image with touching like a scrollview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, touch

Well I have an image and I I want that when I touch it  and then I move my finger it follows it.but I want that it follows it only vertically like a vertical scrollview(but I don't wanna use a scrollview).How can I do this please. sorry for my english I'm french :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why wouldn't you subclass UIScrollView for your view that displays the image? If you do it's pretty simple: define its size so that the horizontal length doesn't exceed the screen length. You'd have to also remember to change this if you allow rotation of the device/view to landscape. Suppose the width of your UIScrollView is 320, you would do this:

```
CGSize scrollableSize = CGSizeMake(320, myScrollableHeight);
[myScrollView setContentSize:scrollableSize];
```

Where `myScrollableHeight` is the full height of the image.

I've never used it but if that doesn't work there is apparently a method you can provide for your UIScrollView class that is called whenever the user attempts to scroll and you can just not adjust the X-coordinate there:

```
float oldX; // make this ivar in your .h file

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
{
    [aScrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(aScrollView.contentOffset.y, oldX)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apple's [MoveMe sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoveMe/Introduction/Intro.html). This should give you an idea. If you only want it to move vertically, only change the y value while dragging.

Comment: but how" can I change the y value while dragging" I don't really understand

Answer (score 0):

Just adding a panning gesture to the image parent view and moving the image.center (only the y in your case) should be enough. Look at [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW1) for more details